# How to buy BTC as a company

Tags: exchanges, business

Is there any other options how an i buy BTC other than on an exchange ?

Why do i ask, we would like to buy BTC as a company which is not in ENG speaking country.

For that reason all paperwork has to be translated and then sent to exchange in order to create a business account - do you have any experience of doing so ?

In the meantime is there any legit way how to buy a BTC as a company ? - do you have any experience of doing so?

Thank you all for information ! stay healthy

Comment: Hi Seznam_psovod, if you can share what country you are located in that may help people to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Are there other options? Short answer: Yes.
Find a person with bitcoins and make an offer. That's how trading works.
Exchanges minimize the risk and centralize the trade. But they do not monopolize it.

English isn't the only option on most exchanges. If you can't find one supporting your language you have to translate, of course.

As Murch already pointed out legality depends on where you are from. So, check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legality_of_bitcoin_by_country_or_territory) to see if bitcoin is legal in your country. Plus I strongly recommend asking a lawyer for legal advice.